# Wamp server not rendering Magento install page

Tags: magento, localhost, wamp

Finally after much research when I couldn't get anything, I'm posting here. I'm trying to install magento on wamp server version 2.1. I extracted the **Magento CE 1.7.0** to 'magento' folder in **c:\wamp\www**. I checked the dependencies and they are all compliant. When I try to access magento through
`http://localhost/magento/`, the url changes to
`http://www.localhost.com/magento/`   and I get a `Connection was reset` error.

What am I missing? If any other information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out your error logs (probably in C:\wamp\logs).

Magento itself should not run on windows (it's possible, but requires a lot of work to get all the PHP modules running).

I would suggest you to install it on a linux/unix server with an Apache installed from the packet manager (no preconfigured packages like LAMP, XAMPP, etc...).
If you don't have access to a linux box and don't have a server try a VM (like VirtualBox).

Trust me, running Magento on linux will be way easier then on windows ;-)

Comment: I understand very well that Magento must live with Linux but I would love to sort out its differences with Windows. :-). As far as modules and logs are concerned, there is nothing I should worry about. I guess it has something to do with virtual host settings. Unfortunately, I am not able to set up vhosts in windows and it has got something to do with Windows 7.

Comment: VHosts are not the problem, this is not necessary for Magento. What I would worry about is the performance (setting up a good running apache including PHP caching modules (like APC)) and the needed PHP modules (like mcrypt library etc...). From my experience I can say setting up a webserver on linux is way easier and more performant than on windows.